# Is there any software package to calculate the entropy, information content, mutual information, etc?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, information-theory

Provided a p.f. of a discrete random variable, or a joint p.f. for several random variable, is there any software package to calculate the entropy, joint entropy, information content, mutual information, etc? If it can be used in a C# program, that'll be great.

Comment: R has a package called [entropy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/entropy/).

Comment: Thanks. If you change your comment to an answer, I will mark it. BTW, is there any Python option?

Comment: Like [this](https://code.google.com/p/pyentropy/)?

Comment: That looks awesome. Could you re-post your 2 comments as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: If you already know the p.m.f. it is not difficult to calculate these quantities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R has a package called [entropy](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/entropy/) which allows you to calculate quantities such as entropy and mutual information. There is also a module called [pyentropy](https://code.google.com/p/pyentropy/) for Python that allows you calculate similar quantities.